# Добавление изменений с ветки на ветку

Tags: git

Добрый день.
Есть ветка `master` и `temp`, как добавить к мастеру ветку temp без изменений в коммитах `3 commit` и `therd commit`(всё равно каким, да, я не умею писать third).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: git merge/git rebase/git cherry-pick - выбирайте

Comment: а какой посоветуете?)

Comment: Вам нужно перенести только два коммита?

Comment: хочу понять сам принцип, т.е. пускай temp - рабочая ветка, в которой есть коммиты костыли(которые помогают работать локальной версии), а есть master, на которую хочу перенести изменения без этих костылей. Ну и соответственно мастер спокойно работает без костылей, так как работает нелокально

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно откатить изменения сделанные в этих коммитах. Օткатить те коммиты которые не нужны вот так:

```
git revert commit-hash
```

`commit-hash` это хеш код коммита, а потом уже можете сделать `merge`.

А хеш коммита можно посмотреть этой [программой](https://blogs.gnome.org/nacho/2016/04/05/gitg-3-20-0-for-windows/).

Comment: Но если, мне всё же нужны эти коммиты, но на мастера хочу перенести  код без них

Comment: @koshachok Другой способ сейчас не помню, но если все таки нужны, то сделайте из текущей ветки новую, и потом удалите коммити из текущей так как я говорил.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по формулировке вопроса - нужно просто перенести всего два комита. Это работа для cherry-pick.

Самый простой способ:

- вначале перейти в ветку temp, сделать git log и запомнить хеши нужных коммитов (можно на листике записать первые 5-6 символов, весь запоминать не нужно).
- переходим в ветку master и делаем дважды `cherry-pick`, последовательно указывая записанные выше хеши:

  ```
  git cherry-pick <хеш>
  ```

  порядок хешей делайте такой, какой Вам нужно. Вполне может такое произойти, что в процессе применения коммита может произойти конфликт - его нужно решить и закоммитить ручками. По умолчанию, cherry-pick делает коммит автоматом. Если этого не хочется (ну мало чего), можно просто добавить параметр `-n`.

  ```
  git cherry-pick -n <хеш>
  ```
- PROFIT!

Можно конечно сделать и через rebase, но думаю, буду дольше рассказывать, а результат будет тот же.